# Error executing phantom js on windows . Invalid json

Tags: php, phantomjs

I am using [phantom library](https://github.com/kriansa/h2p) to convert my highcharts to PDF.

When I execute the code

```
$result = json_decode(trim(shell_exec($this->getBinPath() . ' ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($args)))));
```

Error is returned saying

```
unable to parse json
```

Command being run is

```
 "C:\www\myproject\vendor\kriansa\h2p\bin/win32/phantomjs.exe" "C:\www\myproject\vendor\kriansa\h2p\bin/converter.js" "{ destination : C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\14b6e6edc209b6e731bdbc79976a9430438409ae.tmp , request :{ uri : C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\127ef8f78c335d9af694a9cef0423541dd17a256.html , method : GET }, orientation : Portrait , format : A3 , zoomFactor :1, allowParseCustomFooter :false, allowParseCustomHeader :false, border : 1cm , header :null, footer :null}"
```

What should I check for ? I have validated the json being passed as argument.

**Edit**

I checked this also

```
"C:\www\cimba_aboutmy360\vendor\kriansa\h2p\bin/win32/phantomjs.exe" "C:\www\cimba_aboutmy360\vendor\kriansa\h2p\bin/converter.js" {"destination":"C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\d4ca24267110d5c234b7a006f1ae5c03da248e88.tmp","request":{"uri":"C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\9b5d4d28689c3bc00afc0831666d6ee39a934b5c.html","method":"GET"},"orientation":"Portrait","format":"A3","zoomFactor":1,"allowParseCustomFooter":false,"allowParseCustomHeader":false,"border":"1cm","header":null,"footer":null}
```

same error again

Comment: Have you looked at the output before trying to decode json?

Comment: It is giving me parse error

Comment: That is very invalid JSON (it isn't even valid JS object literal syntax). Use a [lint](http://jsonlint.com/) and learn [json](http://json.org).

Comment: @Quentin . Thanks my friend I very well know about json and its validation .I want know what is wrong with the command that is being executed

Comment: @alwaysLearn — What is wrong is that the JSON you said is valid is not. It manages to have an error (the first of **many**) in the **third** character.

Comment: What is wrong is that the json string you are passing in presumably `$args` IS NOT VALID

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [this tool](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to validate JSON for JS, it has to pass the JS eval tests.

This JSON parses correctly:

```
{ 
    "destination" : "C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\14b6e6edc209b6e731bdbc79976a9430438409ae.tmp",
    "request":
    { 
        "uri" : "C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\127ef8f78c335d9af694a9cef0423541dd17a256.html",
        "method" : "GET"
    }, 
    "orientation" : "Portrait",
    "format" : "A3",
    "zoomFactor" :1, 
    "allowParseCustomFooter" :false, 
    "allowParseCustomHeader" :false, 
    "border" : "1cm",
    "header" :null, 
    "footer" :null
}
```

Notice the quotes around they keys (destination, etc) and quotes around non-native types and strings. You can leave null, boolean, integers, decimals without quotes.

### Edit

I think you also need to wrap the JSON in quotes in the command call

```
"C:\www\cimba_aboutmy360\vendor\kriansa\h2p\bin/win32/phantomjs.exe"  
"C:\www\cimba_aboutmy360\vendor\kriansa\h2p\bin/converter.js"
"{'destination':'C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\d4ca24267110d5c234b7a006f1ae5c03da248e88.tmp','request':{'uri':'C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\9b5d4d28689c3bc00afc0831666d6ee39a934b5c.html','method':'GET'},'orientation':'Portrait','format':'A3','zoomFactor':1,'allowParseCustomFooter':false,'allowParseCustomHeader':false,'border':'1cm','header':null,'footer':null}"
```

Comment: Did you check that through PHP, I had to add 3 backslashes like so `"C:\\\Windows\\\TEMP\\\999999.tmp"` to get PHP to be ok with it. 4 backslashes also works

Comment: I checked that through php..seems there is some error in command formation in the library `escapeshellarg` is removing the quotes around the key